# Alfresco filter people by creator name

Tags: select, alfresco, criteria

I want to modify the webscript `alfresco-remote-api-5.0.d.jar\alfresco\templates\webscripts\org\alfresco\repository\person\people.get.js`. I need to  display for the connected user only user he has created.

I have modify the filter to include username in query.

```
filter = filter + " AND cm:creator:admin";
people.getPeoplePaging(filter, paging, sortBy, sortAsc);
```

This must display only users created by admin.

But it's not working(no  user is returned).
How can i select only users created by a certain  user ?

Comment: can you tell me what is tour final goal.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at below definition of content model I sure , what you want to achieve is not possible ,as person(user) does not have creator property.Below link shows the content model for users.

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2c/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml

https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/COMMUNITYTAGS/V4.2c/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/systemModel.xml

Comment: Hi Krutik, 
I was thinking like that.
All node in alfresco has a creator in  its properties (i don't know if this is really exact) 
As person is an Alfresco node so person has a creator. So i can filter by creator.

Comment: But if this assertions aren't true i can add to the person model  a new aspect with a property to that refere to the creator node ref.

Comment: even if you have made that,that filter which you have specified , only supports filtering users ,  based on userName and not on other properties.You need to write your own custom webscript